# Row total by grand total in redshift or sql

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am looking to divide by row level data of a column with a grand total of that column. Below is the dataset that I have.

```
date       |   sales    |    avg
2018-12-01 |    10      |   10/215
2018-12-02 |    40      |   40/215
2018-12-03 |    40      |   40/215
2018-12-04 |    10      |   10/215
2018-12-05 |    30      |   30/215
2018-12-06 |    20      |   20/215
2018-12-07 |    35      |   35/215
2018-12-08 |    30      |   30/215
Grand total|    215
```

In the Average column I want the data to dividing for the row to the grand total of that column to understand what is the average of that particular day. Our data base uses redshift to extract the data. How can we solve the above problem? Also, I don't want to show the grand total row.

Answer (score 1):

You would use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       sales * 1.0 / sum(sales) over () as sales_ratio
from t;
```

Comment: May I know what does 1.0 that you've multiplied means? Is it like the 100% average that you are trying to take and does this mean we can't even use group by with the window function? Is it possible to use that?

Comment: @ScribbledMind - It causes an implicit coercion of data type.  Otherwise you'd have `int_x / int_y` which *(due to integer maths, and y being greater than x)* would always yield `0` (which you don't want).

Answer (score -1):

I know it's not a best solution but still works and its a another possibility to you.

```
Select *,
    AVG = (sales/(select sum(sales)from your_table))
from your_table
```

Comment: Yeah its true... I will change!

Comment: I feel that the left join would bring too many duplicate rows in place too @MatBailie - Is that right ? As it won't be on a row level and would create t1 * count(t2) number of times for each row in t1.

Comment: @ScribbledMind - The `LEFT JOIN` was on to a result set that always contained exactly one row.  Now duplication, just no point in using `LEFT JOIN` in the first place.

Comment: I use AVG to name a column not to use with a function in this case.

Comment: You still have an integer divided by another integer, where the denominator is always greater than the numerator, which means you'll always get `0`.  A common solution is to use `a * 1.0 / b`

Comment: I understand now what you mean, I'm just putting it as the past example in the question, where wouldn't an _AVG_ be a _percentage of the total_, maybe the question is wrong in that sense.